# How to trigger the 3D transformation widget with G, R or S

Tags: modeling

When I press G, R or S to move, rotate or scale an object, Blender starts transforming the object based on the current mouse pointer location. But I don't want to jump into the translation right away. Instead I want the 3D Widget to appear, and I want to use the handles in the 3D Widget to transform the object.

Is there any setting in blender to make it happen?

I am using Blender 2.8

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Update:**

Starting Blender 3 the setting 'Tool Keys' to 'Active Tool' will achieve the desired result.

[image]

---

I've found an even simpler solution from [Julien Kasper](https://twitter.com/JulienKaspar/status/1288570023620091910?s=20).

Change the following setting, Edit > Preference > Keymap > 3d View > From *Nevigate* to *Gizmos*

[image]

Now pressing tab shows the following menu from from which I can the desired transformation gizmo.

[image]

Now you can switch transformation widget just by Tilde and a quick swipe which is much faster the moving cursor over to toolbox!

Answer (score 2):

First, delete the existing G/R/S bindings by going to Preferences > Keymap > 3D View > 3D View (Global), and scroll down until you find them. Click the "x" button to remove them.

[image: screenshot of the keymap editor where the G/R/S bindings are]

Next, create the new bindings by right click the widget tools in the side panel toolbar, and select "assign shortcut". Then type the key you want the new shortcut to be for that tool.

[image: the right click menu on the toolbar]

Unfortunately, you will need to do this seperately for each mode, such as edit/object/pose modes. And edit mode will need to be done for each object type, edit mode shortcuts for meshes are not the same as for curves or metaballs.

Finally, to make these changes apply to all scenes from now on, bring preferences up again and click "Save Preferences"

[image: location of "save preferences" button in the bottom left of the Preferences window]

Comment: Thank you. Can you please tell me where can I find edit/pose mode? When I search  'G' key-binding in KeyMap, I find a large list of move actions assigned to G, none of which are edit/pose.

Comment: You only need to remove G/R/S once, it will remove it for everything. It’s just setting the new bindings for the widget that needs to be done per-mode

Answer (score 1):

Sorry for this shameless plug, but try my addon. It's very simple and is probably the answer to your question, but it allows you to use the widgets instead of the active tools in a more intuitive way. Also, you don't have to mess with the keymap as much as you would with the active tools (ie setting the keymap for every possible mode). It works much better than the active tools and lets you change the selection mode or switch to the other active tools while the transform gizmo is still active. The bonus is that if you choose the select tool (not box select, lasso, or circle select, but the "Select" tool) the drag behavior is just like on the transform active tools. I'm trying to get the developers to see that this is a far superior way of working.

https://github.com/dpdpforlife/QWER